# Parsing by Delimitor sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a dataframe like below:

```
                 Col1     Col2
123,bnh12,1242,mdmdmd        8
0923,3mdn42,76,ieieie       10
```

How do I parse this dataset by a comma `,` and get an expected output like below in sqldf?

```
                 Col1     Col2    NewCol    NewCol2   
123,bnh12,1242,mdmdmd        8       123        123
0923,3mdn42,76,ieieie       10      0923         76
```

I was able to get the first number for NewCol but can't figure out NewCol2:

```
df1 <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUBSTR([Col1], 1, INSTR([Col1],',')-1) [NewCol] FROM df")
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this in sqldf? I can think of a was but it looks godawful. It would be much easier with ordinary R regex.

Comment: I figured out an ugly workaround too. It needs to be in sqldf because I have to transfer my code to a different team and the only environment I can work in for this data is in R unfortunately

Comment: I'll provide what I have though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NewCol1` use the code in the question and for `NewCol2` use `strFilter` to remove all characters that are not commas or digits.  Then trim digits off both ends and then trim commas off both ends.  Then trim more digits off the left side and then trim commas off the left side.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *,
 SUBSTR(Col1, 1, INSTR([Col1], ',') - 1) NewCol1,
 ltrim(ltrim(trim(trim(strFilter(Col1, ',0123456789'), '0123456789'), ','), 
   '0123456789'), ',') NewCol2
 from df")
```

giving:

```
                   Col1 Col2 NewCol1 NewCol2
1 123,bnh12,1242,mdmdmd    8     123    1242
2 0923,3mdn42,76,ieieie   10    0923      76
```

### h2 database

The above uses the default RSQLite backend but if we use the RH2 backend then we have more string manipulation functions to work with:

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)  # sqldf will notice this is loaded and use it

sqldf("SELECT *, 
       regexp_replace(Col1, ',.*', '') NewCol1,
       regexp_replace(Col1, '^[^,]*,[^,]*,|,[^,]*$', '') NewCol2
       FROM df")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUBSTR([Col1], 1, INSTR([Col1],',')-1) [NewCol] FROM df")

df<- sqldf("SELECT *, replace([Col1], [NewCol], '') [Removal of NewCol] from df")

df <- sqldf("select *, substr([Removal of NewCol], 2) as [Removal of NewCol without comma] from df")

df <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUBSTR([Removal of NewCol without comma], 1, INSTR([Removal of NewCol without comma],',')-1) [Middle_UnImportant] FROM df")

df <- sqldf("SELECT *, replace([Removal of NewCol without comma], [Middle_UnImportant], '') [Anything After] from df")

df <- sqldf("select *, substr([Anything After], 2) as [Anything After without comma] from df")

df <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUBSTR([Anything After without comma], 1, INSTR([Anything After without comma],',')-1) [NewCol2] FROM df")
```